# Delphi - Load Treeview items (nodes) into a ListBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How to load a treeview items into a listbox in Delphi?

```
listbox.items:=treeview.items
```

gives

```
Incompatible types String and TNodes
```

I have no idea. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Items` property of `TListBox` is declared as `TStrings`, and `Items` property of `TTreeView` is `TTreeNodes` - one is not assignable to the other.

You will have to do something like this:

```
procedure AddNode(aStrings: TStrings; aNode: TTreeNode);
var
  iChild: integer;
begin
  aStrings.Add(aNode.Text);
  for iChild := 0 to aNode.Count - 1 do
    AddNode(aStrings, aNode.Item[iChild]);
end;

var 
  iNode: integer;
begin
  listbox.Items.Clear;
  for iNode := 0 to treeView.Items.Count - 1 do
    AddNode(listbox.Items, treeView.Items.Item[iNode]);
```

Comment: Thanks Igor worked perfectly. Could you show me some tutorial for me to learn more about compatiblidades between variables?